# Python querying Redshift fails on "Connection reset by peer" but works with dbeaver

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift

I am trying to query my Redshift DB using python,
I tried both of the following:

with **sqlalchemy**:

```
connection_string = "redshift+psycopg2://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" % (USER, PASS, HOST, str(PORT), DATABASE)
    engine = sa.create_engine(connection_string)
    session = sessionmaker()
    session.configure(bind=engine)
    sess = session()
    sess.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT 1;')
```

with **redshift_connector**:

> ```
> conn = redshift_connector.connect(
> host=HOST,
> port=PORT,
> database=DATABASE,
> user=USER,
> password=PASS)
> cursor = conn.cursor()
> cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT 1;')
> all_results =  cursor.fetchall()
> conn.close()
> ```

both are returning 'Connection reset by peer' while when I am trying to connected using DBeaver I am able to run this query without any problems

anything I might be missing?

Comment: is that the full and exact error message? what version of redshift driver? try using straight postgres driver in python?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error.  In my case it was related to SSL. You can either configure ssl or disable it.  To disable it you may use either of the following options:

**With sqlalchemy:**

```
connection_string = "redshift+psycopg2://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" % (USER, PASS, HOST, str(PORT), DATABASE)
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_string, connect_args={'ssl': False})
session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
sess = session()
results = sess.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT 1;')
results.fetchall()
```

**with redshift_connector:**

```
conn = redshift_connector.connect(host=HOST,
                                  port=PORT,
                                  database=DATABASE,
                                  user=USER,
                                  password=PASS,
                                  ssl=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE LIMIT 1;')
all_results =  cursor.fetchall()
```